# Is EasyRepro still being maintained?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, microsoft-dynamics, easyrepro

Is anyone using the Dynamics 365 automation utility `EasyRepro` actively in their projects?. There have only been a few commits recently to the repository with some PRs dating back to 2023. I am asking because I saw some posts mentioning that `EasyRepro` is no longer being maintained but really wanted to try it out.

Basically I want to automate some UI tests on dynamics 365 and was looking for the best tools to do so, If there is something else like EasyRepro that I should look into please let me know.